# Mac Catalyst UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout error

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, mac-catalyst

I have the following `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`:

```
public lazy var layout: UICollectionViewLayout = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                             heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                              heightDimension: .absolute(115))

        var count: Int = 2
        if self.view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != .compact {
            if self.view.frame.size.width > 900 {
                count = 5
            } else {
                count = 3
            }
        }

        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: count)
        let spacing = CGFloat(10)
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(spacing)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = spacing
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        return section
    }
    return layout
}()
```

When I run this on iOS it works fine, but when I run this on Mac using Catalyst, it will throw the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot solve for a non-group item.'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This looks like a production bug: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124504